# Unboundedness of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Given a function f on R is continuous and also it satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)|≥K|x-y|$ for all x,y in R. This function is one-one, which is clear but how to prove such functions are unbounded? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $y=0$. Then $|f(x)-f(0)|\ge K |x|$. Then the triangle inequality implies $|f(x)|+|f(0)| \ge |f(x)-f(0)| \ge K |x|$. Then $|f(x)| \ge K|x| - |f(0)|$.

Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $f$ is bounded by $M$.  If you choose $x$ such that $ M< K |x| - |f(0)|$, which is accomplished by $|x| > (M+|f(0)|)/K$, you break the bound. Therefore, $f$ is unbounded.

I've had three beers, factor that into your estimation of the quality of the answer.

Comment: Here we are not making use of the assumption of continuity of function. So does the result hold for a discontinuous function?

Comment: Continuity is not used here.

Comment: Continuity is not used, no. The thing about continuity is that it is mostly about what happens in neighborhoods of points. You have a "reverse Lipschitz" condition, sometimes called "nonvanishing variation" or rarely "regular" when I have seen people try to give it a name. You don't need continuity because you are forcing the function to move apart as $x$ and $y$ diverge, not trying to constrain it to stay within a cone like a Lipschitz condition. But I am up to more beers so my comment is even less reliable.

Comment: This covid thing is a real bummer. I miss my colleagues and talking about math. Even the one that says everything is "trivial" and "obvious" and constantly argues with invited speakers during their talks.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $K > 0$.

Hint: if $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge K |x-y|$, at least one of $|f(x)|$ and $|f(y)|$ is ...